# Bitmap BMP Reading Question: I need to read (large) 8MB 32BPP BMP Files into Memory so they may be queued for game play

Tags: c++, 2d, graphics, game-loop

```
class Surface 
{
protected:
    Surface();
    virtual ~Surface();

    class IMAGE // create a discreet type to be used to instantiate queue template
    {
    public:
        // single bitmap image width and height
        unsigned short width, height;
        unsigned int size;      // single bitmap image size
        DWORD* buffer;          // buffer to hold a width X height _size_ image
…

class Bitmap : protected Surface
{
public:
    class BMP_32
    {
    public:
        BMPHeader       HeaderSection;
        BMPInfo         InfoSection;
        BMPColorTable       ColorTableSection;

…

void Bitmap::BMP_32::Read(Bitmap::BMP_32& a_bmp32, IMAGE& an_image, SURFACE& a_surface, const char* file_name)
{
…
fread(&a_bmp32.HeaderSection.FileType, sizeof(a_bmp32.HeaderSection.FileType), 1, fp);
…
fread(&a_bmp32.InfoSection.HeaderSize, sizeof(a_bmp32.InfoSection.HeaderSize), 1, fp);
…
fread(&a_bmp32.ColorTableSection.RedIntensity, sizeof(a_bmp32.ColorTableSection.RedIntensity), 1, fp);
…

an_image.buffer = new DWORD[IMAGEBUFFERSIZE];

…
// The following three examples render the same output visually:

// DWORD dwords_read = fread(an_image.buffer, sizeof(DWORD), an_image.size, fp);  // dwords_read = 2,073,600

DWORD dwords_read = fread(an_image.buffer, (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT), 4, fp);   // dwords_read = 4
// DWORD dwords_read = fread(an_image.buffer, ((SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2), 2, fp);  // dwords_read = 2
```

Background Detail: I am building up a class framework to read in 32BPP BMP files, that I am creating on a backsurface, which I then bltfast to the frontsurface and flip to GDI. The 32BPP background BMP that I am reading in is 8294400 in size, but the most I am able to read using “fread()” is 2073600, which is exactly 25% of the original artwork. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and fread(&MyBuffer, arg2, arg3, stream) extensively. My application is an MFC application.

I have a need to read in the entire BMP Pixel Data Section into memory, because I am saving this into a queue Abstract Data type. Once I have the BMP in memory the I/O is done to disk and I just make calls to update the backsurface, bltfast and flip to update my scene. I am creating a class library for the BMP code.

Question: Is fread() hitting an upperbound on size limit? If so can someone suggest how I might be able to overcome this problem. If so I am hoping to make a minor substitution for this fread() API call for another C++ call. I cannot do anything too fancy with multiple buffers or doing a lot of I/O, as I have tried that approach already without success.

Comment: What is the value of `an_image.size` and `IMAGEBUFFERSIZE`?

Comment: // some useful constants

#define SCREEN_WIDTH    1920
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   1080
#define BPP             32      // Bits Per Pixel
#define IMAGEBUFFERSIZE ( SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT ) * BPP // holds max IMAGE size;

an_image.size == 8294400 // size of the raw pixel data from this specific 32 BPP BMP

// here is how I obtained it --

fread(&a_bmp32.InfoSection.ImageSize, sizeof(a_bmp32.InfoSection.ImageSize), 1, fp);
an_image.size = a_bmp32.InfoSection.ImageSize;


I have set the value of IMAGEBUFFERSIZE much higher than I believe it needs to be

Thanks for taking a peek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following to work well.
from working code that I wrote some time back,
which I now converted to utilize 32BPP BMP files and x64.

For the 32BPP header file I used the following link:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/11/19/cpp-reading-writing-bmp-images/

In case your wondering I am using DirectX 7.0

```
class Bitmap
{
public:

    class BMP32
    {
    public:

        BMPHeader       HeaderSection;
        BMPInfo         InfoSection;
        BMPColorTable   ColorTableSection;
        BYTE* buffer;           // buffer to hold a BMP raw pixel data


        BMP32() {
            memset(&HeaderSection, 0, sizeof(HeaderSection));
            memset(&InfoSection, 0, sizeof(InfoSection));
            memset(&ColorTableSection, 0, sizeof(ColorTableSection));
            buffer = NULL;
        }

        virtual ~BMP32() { if (buffer != NULL && InfoSection.ImageSize != 0) delete buffer; }
        void Read(BMP32& a_bmp32, const char* file_name); // read that will read 32BPP
    };
...

class Surface...

class IMAGE     // create a discreet type to be used to instantiate a queue of surfaces
    {
    public:
        int width, height;      // single bitmap image width and height
        unsigned int size;      // single bitmap image size
        DWORD* buffer;          // buffer to hold a width X height _size_ image
        IMAGE() { buffer = NULL; width = 0; height = 0; size = 0; }
        virtual ~IMAGE() { if (buffer != NULL && size != 0) delete buffer; }    // don't leak memory!
    };

...

void ReadGFX(const char* file_name, PALETTEENTRY scene_palette[MAX_COLORS_PALETTE]); // read in all 32 bit bmp images from the gfx (aka the sprite library) file name passed to this method
    

// What we want to do here is to read a file containing one or more
// bmp files. each bmp read will be written into a ddraw surface.
// The bmp file consists of a header ( width  height and size ) and data ( size bytes )
void Sprite::ReadGFX(const char* file_name, PALETTEENTRY scene_palette[MAX_COLORS_PALETTE])
{

    TRACE("Sprite::ReadGFX invoked. GFX name is : %s\n", file_name );

    
    FILE* fp;                           // file pointer to opened file_name
    if ( ( fp = fopen(file_name,"rb") ) != NULL )
    {
    
        short image_count = 0, i = 0;               // number of sprite images contained in file_name
        int w = 0, h = 0;
        unsigned int size = 0;
        DWORD buffer_size = 0;

        fread(&image_count, sizeof(image_count), 1, fp);    // get number of bmp files to read
        

        for ( i = 1; i <= image_count; i++ )
        {
            IMAGE an_image;     // create enough local storage to read in one image
            SURFACE a_surface;

        w = fread(&an_image.width,  sizeof(an_image.width), 1, fp);         // bmp width
        h = fread(&an_image.height, sizeof(an_image.height), 1, fp);        // bmp height
        size =  fread(&an_image.size,   sizeof(an_image.size), 1, fp);      // bmp size

        TRACE("Sprite::Read an_image.width = %d, an_image.height = %d, an_image.size = %d\n", w, h, size);
            an_image.buffer = new DWORD[an_image.size]; // create enough storage to hold bmp data
            buffer_size = fread(an_image.buffer, sizeof(BYTE), an_image.size, fp);  // read the raw pixel data from the bmp here 
            try
            {
                Create(an_image.width, an_image.height, a_surface); // create ddraw surface
                Write(an_image, a_surface, Scene::scene_palette);               // copy image into surface
                surface_queue.Enqueue(a_surface);   // save data structure by queueing record object
                TRACE("Width = %i, Height = %i, Size = %i, Buffer Size = %u\n", w, h, size, buffer_size);
            }
            catch (int exception)
            {
                TRACE("%Xh exception caught by Sprite::ReadGFX\n ", exception);
                if (exception == VIDEO_EXCEPTION)
                {
                    TRACE("VIDEO_EXCEPTION caught by Sprite::ReadGFX, due to Surface::Create failure\n");
                    TRACE("Terminating: throwing SPRITE_EXCEPTION\n");
        
                    // clean up to avoid memory leaks!!
                    if (!surface_queue.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        surface_queue.MakeEmpty();
                    }
                    if (  an_image.buffer != NULL && an_image.size != 0   )
                    {
                        delete an_image.buffer;
                        an_image.buffer = 0;
                        an_image.buffer = NULL;
                    }
                    fclose(fp); // close the input file
                    throw (SPRITE_EXCEPTION); // terminate the program
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE ("Sprite::ReadGFX %s not found\n", file_name);
        char message[60];
        strcpy ( message, "Graphics file not found: ");
        strcat ( message, file_name);
        strcat ( message, "\nApplication will now terminate.");
        FatalMessageBox( message );
        throw (SPRITE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```